# Canonical equation of a line in space: horizontal and vertical lines

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry, 3d

I have a question about canonical equation of a line in 3d space: how can I handle vertical and horizontal lines? One of direction vector's values will be just $0$, but this will mess up the equation, because I can't put $0$ value in denominator. Can I just describe vertical line using only $x$ and $z$ coordinates of its points?

Comment: What is the "canonical" equation of a line ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: equation containing direction vector and coordinates of a point lying on the line. Maybe I'm just using wrong english term - please correct me. I was refering to [this](http://onlinemschool.com/math/library/analytic_geometry/line/#h10).

Comment: You cannot write the equation in that form if the line is parallel to one of the axes.

Comment: @Aretino: so how can I handle them? Using one of the different equastions is the only solution?

Comment: Yes. The same thing happens in 2d, where you cannot write the equation of a line in the form $y=mx+q$ if it is directed along the $y$-axis.

Comment: Ok, I thought there may be some trick that I'm not aware of. Thank you!

Comment: @Aretino what about x = c ?

Comment: @Integral That equation is not of the requested form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will sometimes find the conventional notation

$$\frac{x-x_0}l=\frac{y-y_0}m=\frac{z-z_0}n$$

with a zero allowed at the denominator, like

$$\frac{x-x_0}l=\frac{y-y_0}0=\frac{z-z_0}n,$$

which must be interpreted as $y=y_0$.

You cannot drop this condition, as

$$\frac{x-x_0}l=\frac{z-z_0}n$$

alone is the equation of a plane (parallel to the $y$ axis).

The parametric equation avoids the singular cases while using exactly the same parameters, so it can be preferred.